# Trigonometry: Applications

Tags: trigonometry

A helicopter is flying due west over level ground at an attitude of 222 m, and at a constant speed. From point A, which is due west of the helicopter, two measurements of the angle between the ground and the helicopter are taken. The first angle measurement is 6 degrees and the second measurement, taken one minute later is 75 degrees. If the helicopter has not yet passed over Point A, how fast is the helicopter travelling to the nearest kilometer per hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints**: Have you drawn a picture? Perhaps with two right triangles, both of which have adjacent side $222$? Do you know what SOHCAHTOA means? Do you know how to convert between meters and kilometers? What about minutes and hours?